# Test Existing Natural Gas Barbecue Line Without a Hose

Tags: safety, natural-gas

I have a natural gas hookup on my back deck and want to purchase a natural gas barbecue. There is a quick connect at the hookup and a valve to turn it on, but when I turn it on I don't feel any pressure (gas coming out after a few seconds). This pipe runs from the basement where there is another valve for it which I had also turned on. There is a three way splitter in the basement, one pipe to the hot water tank, one to the fireplace, and one to the outside hookup (which has its own regulator). Both the hot water tank and fireplace work.

Is there a way to safely test to see if gas is actually coming out? Do I need to leave it on for a while? I'm not inclined to try this unless it's my only option. I don't want to purchase a grill and have it assembled if the natural gas line doesn't work.

Thanks,
Ron g5spville

Edit: I turned on both valves, held a glass of water over the end of the quick connect and pulled back the sleeve, but there were no bubbles even after about 30 seconds. So mayber I need to have a hose connected in order for the gas to flow(?), or else it's just not working.

Comment: I am not going to look this up; I'm just going to suggest this: The quick connect hookup may have a valve in it which is closed by a spring and opens when the other half of the quick connect fitting is pushed on. You might have to get something to simulate connecting a quick connect fitting. Certainly compressed air hoses have that property. If gas is coming out, you should be able to hear it and smell it .

Comment: Normal low pressure gas is 7 inches of water column or something like 0.25 psig. What happens if you turn on the valves and hold the end of the hose barely underwater in cup?

Comment: I suspect @JimStewart is right about the valve within the disconnect.  That's pretty standard.  It is probably even code on a non-permanent flammable gas connection.

Comment: If the end of the quick connect is female and it's like a compressed air hose, there is a spring loaded sleeve on the outside that you push back by hand to open the valve. You don't need anything pushed in.

Comment: Thanks @JimStewart, I was wondering whether or not you needed a hose plugged in, or even just to hold the sleeve open. I will check it out.

Comment: You will have to hold the sleeve open with you hand unless the other side is plugged in.

Comment: If you still can't get anything out, try turning the valve off, remove the hose with the quick coupler, then slowly turn the valve on, if you have gas, turn it off, your hose will need to be connected to activate and allow gas to flow like the other comments suggest.